# Visual studio 2010 Implement Interface - Copy XML comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I have a class that is implementing an interface, I can right click on the interface name in that class file and choose to "Implement Interface". Visual Studio 2010 will automatically populate my class with the required methods and fields.

Can Visual Studio 2010 be configured to also copy the XML summary comments attached to those methods / fields to the new class file?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Visual Studio can't do this out-of-the-box.

You could install [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which will give you exactly the functionality you are searching for or use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which will make it easy to get the base commenting for your interface.

Hope that helps!